# Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()

Tags: android, google-maps

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>
> I try to find nearby place .... this kind of error I get.... help me
>   What kind of changes i apply plz guide me

```js
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;

    String[] mPlaceType=null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
       int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }
        else
        { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String place = mPlaceTypeName[selectedPosition];

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("types=place");
                    sb.append("&location="+mLatitude+", "+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=10000");
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=[My API Key]");

                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }

    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Log:

08-19 14:52:02.145  22460-22460/com.example.admin.newmapplace E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.example.admin.newmapplace, PID: 22460
                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                        at com.example.admin.newmapplace.MapsActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:245)
                        at com.example.admin.newmapplace.MapsActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:215)
                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: there should (well, there is for sure) be the file and the line which generated the issue. I suppose it is something in the adapter that is not filled with data.
Please post the full log.
In any case, this is nothing to do with google-maps but general programming

Comment: see i attach full log....@NDorigatti

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite explanatory:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                    at com.example.admin.newmapplace.MapsActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:245)
                    at com.example.admin.newmapplace.MapsActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:215)
```

If you check in the ParserTask onPostExecute, that line (215 or 245) should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
```

And the issue is that, that method receives a null "list" item, which is taken from the method parameter:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){
```

It is null because your "doInBackground" method returns a null object, looking at your code:

```
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }
```

It seems that an exception is raised and then "places" is not set, leading to a null object returned. If you check the log (you set Debug, it's better to do Log.e in this cases), you should se a line with "Exception" and the text of the exception.
An alternative for logging exception:

```
Log.e(TAGOFMESSAGE,"Raised an exception during doInBackground Method",e);
```

This will log an error and will put the stack trace of the exception in the log, helping you understanding what raised the exception.